# I cant find a saved symbols or graphic styles when i start to work on a new file. how to fix this problem?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-library

i saved a symbol on adobe illustrator to work on later, but when I open a new file I cant find the symbol anymore on library. I realized this happened when i tried to save graphic styles as well. What could the reason be?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Symbols exist at the document level, not in Illustrator itself. Open the document you last used the symbol in, then click and drag it into your new document.

Comment: thank you so much! I didn't know that.